# Error while installing Word VSTO

Tags: vsto

I'm getting an error while trying to install a Microsoft Word VSTO Addin that I made in Visual Studio 2015 on a Windows 10 Computer.

#### The error that I'm getting - screenshot

[image: The error that I'm getting - screenshot]

I am on a domain server, and I don't have access to the path specified by the error message.  Is there any way to change that path to a different path?

Complete Error Text:

```
Name: <Name of Application>
From: file:///E:/<Name of Application>/<Name of Application>.vsto

************** Exception Text **************
System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException: Downloading file:///E:/<Name of Application>/Application Files/<Name of Application>_1_0_0_1/<Name of Application>.dll.deploy did not succeed. ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Users\*********\AppData\Local\Temp\Deployment\Y3Q7BGZC.PJH\WH8KGN6M.K6H\<Name of Application>.dll' is denied.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.DownloadAddIn(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.InstallAddIn()
```